# Stop Textbox on Canvas Capturing Focus

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, focus

I have a `Canvas` inside of a `ScrollViewer`, and a `UserControl` placed on that canvas. The `UserControl` itself contains, among other things, a `Textbox`. The arrangement looks something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer DoubleTapped="ScrollViewer_DoubleTapped">
    <Canvas>
        <UserControl>
            <Textbox></Textbox>
        </UserControl
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am trying to implement double-tap to zoom (by handling the `DoubleTapped` event of the `ScrollViewer`. It works correctly, and as expected, for double-clicking with a mouse, and double-tapping on a trackpad. It does not work properly for a touchscreen, however.

The issue appears to be that the `Textbox` on the `UserControl` captures the focus whenever the `ScrollViewer` is tapped. Mouse and track-pad don't seem to care, but the touch screen double-tap appears to start the zoom, but then stop shortly afterwards when the focus is captured.

How can I stop the `Textbox` from capturing the focus whenever I click on the `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: Hmmm, just a shot in the dark without testing but you might start with trying `IsTabStop="False"` on that parent UserControl (shouldn't be necessary on the TextBox itself) since that behavior might be expected there.

Comment: Thank you! That did indeed stop the UserControls from capturing the focus. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my original problem... so something else must be preventing the double-tap to zoom.

Comment: Do you get any output from the event for double tapped? Another shot in the dark would be Canvas is maybe blocking the event propagation in which case I'd ask if Canvas is being used just to do quickie layout with a bunch of fixed Margins and stuff, or if it could maybe be accomplished a bit more properly with something like `Grid`, but I'd need to see more code to make a better opinion.

Comment: The canvas is being used because users can freely drag and reposition elements on the canvas. It is necessary. Is there a way to test if the canvas is blocking? I double tap on the canvas itself when this problem occurs. The scrollviewer appears to zoom slightly, but very far from doubling. What doesn't make sense to me is what's causing tapping on the touch screen to behave differently than double click with a mouse or double tap on the trackpad.